# Dashing mechanic in top down projectile dodging game in pygame

Tags: physics, movement, pygame

im making a simple third person top down game where you dodge projectiles than fly in from either side of the screen, its a simple high score game where the longer you avoid being hit, the better your score.
i want to give the player the ability to dash in any movable direction by using a resource (lets call it a dashcoin)
if the player collides with a certain target, they get one dashcoin, which can be expended to dash forward at increased speed for a brief moment. im also hoping to remove player control while they dash
this is the entirety of the code right now. currently theres no projectiles to dodge, but im working on that.

````
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((630, 530))

pygame.display.set_caption("Cube Dash")

x = 250
y = 250
width = 30
height = 30
vel = 3

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(10)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 60:
        x -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 550:
        x += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > 10:
        y -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 490:
        y += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        run = False

    win.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()```

im completely new to pygame and got most of this from tutorials, so any help is appreciated
````

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable goal. Where did you run into trouble implementing it that we can help you overcome?

Comment: its not a problem of having trouble implementing it, its more that i dont know what to do first
i have a general idea of how the movement works, but i dont know enough to start adding a new movement mechanic from scratch, i just need pointed in the right direction

Comment: Well, think through it logically. Your character has two states, dashing and not dashing. When they're not dashing, you want to use the control code you have now. When they are dashing, you want to move them in their dash direction until the dash time is over. That sounds like a job for an `if`. Show us how you'd implement that basic skeleton, and let us know what you still need beyond that.

Comment: i decided not to remove control from the character while dashing, just as a test, and instead multiply their speed by 2 while holding space, however now pressing space simply crashes the game...

```vel = 2

dash = False
            
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        dash = True
    while dash:
        vel = 4``` it doesnt look like the site wants me to enter more code...

Comment: You probably noticed that comments are not made for sharing significant amounts of code. If you have updates to make to your question, click the "Edit" link at the bottom of your question.